# RadAjaxLoadingPanel Disappears after some time

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am facing a problem regarding RadAjaxLoadingPanel. I have to save different records from Excel or CSV file to my database using Open Access.
When query start on and data in being saved in DB, loading panel is working fine but after some time when certain amount of records are saved(say 350 records) to DB than loading panel hides and does not show any progress while data in saving in DB. I studied about MinDisplayTime property of RadAjaxLoadingPanel but i need to set this property according to my number of records so that loading panel should be displayed until all records are saved to DB.

For brief description I am attaching working video of my problem
.You will see in the video that loading panel disappears after some time while records are being saved to DB continuously but loading panel disappears.

this is video link.
http://screencast.com/t/oSkjTDheo

What should  I do to show the loading panel until all my records are saved to DB ?
Can some one help my ASAP.

Regards:
Kamran

Answer (score 1):

The two minute page request timeout has expired.  The browser will wait two minutes on a request before it stops waiting.

Several things that I am seeing as part of this operation:

1. This is a synchronous operation that you are demonstrating to load data.  You may want to use the recommended [RadAsyncUpload control](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/asyncupload.aspx) to load the file.  In this way, you are immediately  returning control to the page.  You can then perform your data load asynchronously behind the scenes and display a progress meter as the data is loaded.
2. Your data load rate is roughly 3 records per second.  That is very slow, what process are you using to load this data?  500 records should load into a single table in just a few seconds.

Comment: Thanx for Response Jeff. Actually i am loading data after complete validation of each record. For example, I am validating Email,PhoneNumber,Name with regular expressions and than after complete validation of data I am inserting that data to DB. And if a reocrd does not meet the validation process than I put that data in DB with some tag to specify that this is an invalid data column.

Comment: Now what should I do for fast insertion of Data to DB OR make the loading panel remain visible until all records should saved to DB ?

Comment: I am using TelerikOpenAccess to save data.

Comment: It looks like you are committing each row individually... wait until all of the data is added to the context and then commit the entire batch.

Comment: A loop is working on excel sheet, gets the record and than save each record one by one. I did not get your point about committing the entire batch ?

Comment: If you say, I can give you the code for saving data through OpenAccess .